# jQuery equivalent to Prototype Ajax.Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, prototypejs

What would be the jQuery equivalent to the following Prototype AJAX Request?

```
function showSnapshotComments(snapshot) {
   new Ajax.Request('/photos/show_snapshot_comments/'+ snapshot.id,
                    {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true});
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/photos/show_snapshot_comments/'+ snapshot.id,
  async: true,
  dataType: 'script'
});
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function

```
function showSnapshotComments(snapshot) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/photos/show_snapshot_comments/' + snapshot.id,
        dataType: 'script'
    }); 
}
```

or the [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) function if you prefer which is equivalent:

```
function showSnapshotComments(snapshot) {
    $.getScript('/photos/show_snapshot_comments/' + snapshot.id); 
}
```